# perl one line script with condition

Tags: perl, comparison-operators

I have some text file. E.g.

```
1;one;111
2;two;222
22;two;222
3;three;333
```

I try to select line that contains "one" using perl-oneliner:

```
perl -F";" -lane 'print if $F[1]=="one"' forPL.txt
```

But I get all lines from file. 
I don't need use regular expression(reg exp helps in this case), I need exactly match on second field.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Use `eq` for string comparison instead of `==` which is used for numeric comparison.

```
perl -F";" -e 'print if $F[1] eq "one" ' test.txt
```

Edit: As toolic has suggested in his comment, if you had used warnings, you could have easily spot the issue.

```
$ perl -F";" -e 'use warnings; print if $F[1] == "one" ' test.txt 
Argument "one" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1, <> line 1.
Argument "one" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1, <> line 1.
1;one;111
Argument "two" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1, <> line 2.
2;two;222
Argument "two" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1, <> line 3.
22;two;222
Argument "three" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1, <> line 4.
3;three;333
```